# Help identifying the audio up/down switch in a Roku remote control

Tags: pcb, switches, identification

My sound down button isn't working in the Roku 3 remote control. I've opened it up to find that the rocker broke off. The Sound Up has `B S` marking and the Sound Down has `G S`. On the other side (metallic cover) of the switch, both the Sound Up and Down have `B3B17A1`

Anyone knows the manufacturer of these switches, or a compatible replacement?

[image]
[image]
enter code here

Answer (score 2):

These look similar: [Panasonic](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/EVQ-PUA02K/P10847SCT-ND/286348), [Panasonic](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/EVQ-P7A01P/P16763CT-ND/4429456), [E-Switch](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/e-switch/TL1014BF160QG/EG5042CT-ND/3910808). But you need to check the dimensions.
You can search for more on DigiKey in: Product Index > Switches > Tactile Switches and by selecting "mounting type" as "Surface Mount, Right Angle".